# restricting rights of user account and applications for safety, protecting home directory contents from accidents

Tags: permissions, rm, group, home, filezilla

I recently had a terrible accident with filezilla which has literally cost me days to fix. In the course of 2 years of using Linux Mint (Ubuntu kernel) this is the third time I've managed to kill the system, have learnt something every time. Hardware has not yet caused a problem, more human error/ignorance. This time, it killed Windows 7 as well which sits on a physically separate hard drive in the case. I had mounted the Windows drive to access a file as the accident occurred and it somehow must have destroyed something in there quite badly.

So yeah, I was just trying to update a website and saw all this stuff in the left panel of `filezilla` so pressed delete to get rid of it, thinking it was just some old folders from the previous time I updated the site and it was the whole file system! So it all froze, used `xkill` to close it and over the next hours `ext4magic` to recover some files which somewhat worked, but unfortunately Linux and windows both needed to be reinstalled. Was now at least able to put Linux on the bigger drive but don't want this to happen again.

Why on Earth does a program like Filezilla which is there to move files to and from servers need to have the power to destroy a computer?!

So have been wanting to set up things for safety. Created another user account called "admin_acc" from the gui and took away my user accounts admin rights. My user account is still a member of `adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare` . Is that too many for safety?

Have installed [safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm). Although the command `cat /etc/safe-rm.conf` lists all the 25 protected folders, including `/` and `/home` , the user-specific blacklist which is supposed to live in `~/.safe-rm` does not exist! Do I have to simply create it myself? Installed safe-rm from the Mint installer wonder if it was the full version.. I'd like to have all the main folders and hidden folders of the home directory in that custom list.

Am scared that that's not even enough though.. Apparently `safe-rm` just places a wrapper around `rm` and the full path `/bin/rm` still runs it as usual. Who's to know what command filezilla or some other program is going to execute in the background?

Can see that applications as well as users can belong to groups as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29159/why-is-it-recommended-to-create-a-group-and-user-for-some-applications#29165) post. **The goal is that nothing other than the superuser can delete any folders or hidden out of /home or /home/Documents or /home/pictures etc** ever again.. What's the best way of achieving this, how many different measures need to be taken? No use just taking away filezilla's power need to make sure that no other application is going to be like a weapon sitting around waiting for someone to carelessly pull the trigger..

Would be much grateful for some expert guidance here so my fresh, clean install can run peacefully for a long time now.

Comment: This is probably going to be closed as too broad (and rightfully so IMO). Nevertheless, you should start by setting up sensible backups, before investigating ways to protect your files from yourself...

Comment: Starting to use a normal user account instead of admin account is a good start and much more effective than any trickery that tries to avoid mistakes (e.g. `safe-rm`), especially as you already assumed `filezilla` won't necessarily be executing `rm`, at least not without full absolute path to it. The sad side of it is that you'll always be allowed to mess up those things you have write access to, so maybe it would be better to learn to think twice before deleting anything?

Comment: Thanks, I will think twice. Almost everything was backed up but it has still been stressful. Would like to be able to use my account a bit carefree but know if it's an admin account or type `sudo` to tread very carefully. Ok will skip safe-rm just wonder if I need to remove the membership of this account from any of the groups.Will not being admin stop a user deleting their own high level directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use FileZilla as root or to connect as a root user. A normal user usually cannot do what you have described (not without sudo or su or a really misguided sudoers config (e.g., NOPASSWD)). You need to understand that there are two sides as well. Say you are a normal user on host1 and use FileZilla to connect to host2, you can still destroy host2 if you connect as the root user.

As long as you run programs as a normal user and connect to other hosts as a normal user, you usually can't do much damage outside of that user's home directory. If your website files are located somewhere else (e.g., /var/www), then you can either recursively chown those files or more appropriately, add the normal user to a group that can read/write to those files (e.g., www-data).

The concept of user permissions is actually really simple, yet complicated to explain. I suggest investing a few hours to a day in research on the subject to get a basic understanding, learn about the 4-2-1 rule and such.

Also, as you said yourself, you do not know what FileZilla is going to do ... you may want to consider using more basic tools like `ssh` and `sftp`. It pays to learn these things and you also have more power to restrict yourself (e.g., aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` may be good for you).

P.S. I doubt filezilla actually killed your Windows partition from what sounds like a `rm -rf /`. Rather, it probably took out the bootloader.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned it's not just about doing damage outside the home directory but inside of it.. I don't want to use Windows anymore but it did have system restore and recycle bin. Okay good to know it is not supposed to have been possible. Have a lot of reading to do. The first user account Linux Mint makes for you is an admin one. Now I know to make another one and use the gui to make sure it's not admin. Interesting re recursively chown files will investigate that.

Comment: Definitely look into aliasing a few commands:  
`alias mv='mv --interactive'`
`alias cp='cp --interactive'`                                                   
`alias rm='rm --interactive'`
These will help you by confirming deletion of files or overwrite in the case of `cp` and `mv`. However, the `-f, --force` argument can override this.

Comment: Also, `Back in Time`, `System Back`, and `CrashPlan` are all good programs that can be used to replace the system restore that you are used to. Of course, you can also do this with common tools like `rsync`, `tar`, or `cp` automated through cron jobs, but the above are easier for a newcomer. Just know that for a system backup, you need to preserve permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is that nothing other than the superuser can delete any folders or hidden out of /home

This is already true, only root can edit things directly inside `/` by default. You user, by default, should only be able to modify things inside your home directory and /tmp (as well as a few other non critical locations.)

The only way `filezilla` can nuke a whole file system is if it has write access to the whole file system. Which sounds to me like you are running it as root, or if it was a remote system you nuked connecting to it as root. There is not much that you can do to protect yourself if you are running/logging in as root, which is why this is generally discouraged.

Be very careful what you run as root - such as running things with `sudo`, `kdesu`, `gtksu`, `su` - they all give the application root permissions by default. Only run things using those tools that actually require it and not as a reflex for "permission denied" or other errors.

Foremost this is a lesson in backup - you should have some. I find it much easier to have all my systems disposable, I can lose any one of them without worrying about lost data, all I lose is time to set them up again. This is will also not only protect you against mistakes you make, but also against hardware failure and lost/stolen hardware.

The easiest way is an external hard disk drive that you regularly back up to or use tools like dropbox.

In addition to a proper backup system you can use the snapshotting ability of some filesystem (like [btrfs](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-manage-btrfs-storage-pools-subvolumes-and-snapshots-linux-part-1)/zfs) or [llvm](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_snapshots) to keep snapshots of your system you can recover in the case you do something like this again - but they are not full backup solutions, just allow for quicker recovery in the case of some failures.

Comment: Thanks, yes, time, I also have it on various systems and external hard drives. The "Users and Groups" GUI in Linux Mint has two settings, "standard" and "administrator" for users. Yes, good habit not as a reflex for "permission denied" to type sudo I'm considering having different password for it I have to look up. Assume that "root" and "administrator" are the same thing. Mint has made the admin account a member of only the group "sudo" although the user accounts have six group memberships. The "sudo" membership probably gives it everything it needs.

Comment: Root and administrator are not exactly the same. Root is an actual user, admin rights I am guessing mean user that can sudo (ie added to the sudo or wheel group). The user does not have an special permissions by itself, only through sudo (or policykit). Either way you should be required to enter your password to gain access to root privileges - when ever something does be careful/mindful of what it is trying to do.